# Rails tagging fail when printing the name of the tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, model, tagging

I am busy building a tagging system in RoR. 
This system I've coded according to: http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i3:-tagging
Now when I print out tag.name it works but I also get what looks like the entire tag_list as an object printed out directly next to it. The view render in my browser clarifies my problem:

#

*Post*

Tags: [ tag1 tag2 tag3 [#, #, #] ]

Where each bracket actually shows as: Tag id: 27, name: "tag1", created_at: "2015-05-12 09:24:02", updated_at: "2015-05-12 09:24:02"> ... times three (in this case.)

#

(Somehow Stackoverflow doesn't show the completeness of the mess that I am dealing with in my browser but just brackets.)

... as a direct consequence of this piece of code in show.html.haml:

```rb
Tags: [
= @post.tags.each do |tag|
    = link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag)
]
```

And I want it simply to be like this:

#

*Post*

Tags: [ tag1 tag2 tag3 ]

#

Or even without the brackets. Doesn't matter.
My post.rb model looks like this:

```rb
    has_many :taggings
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings

    def tag_list=(tags_string)
        tag_names = tags_string.split(",").collect{|s| s.strip.downcase}.uniq
        new_or_found_tags = tag_names.collect { |name| Tag.find_or_create_by(name: name) }
        self.tags = new_or_found_tags
    end

    def tag_list
        self.tags.collect do |tag|
          tag.name
        end.join(", ")
    end
```

And my routes.rb looks like this:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'posts#index'

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :tags
end
```

I am aware that there are gems for tagging, but for me it is very important to have full control over the tags for the development after this.
The tags will eventually go through complex javascript visualization libraries.
It's probably something very small. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
= @post.tags.each do |tag|
    = link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag)
```

with:

```
- @post.tags.each do |tag|
    = link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag)
```

the `=` prints the collection

Comment: I can not believe that it was that simple. I really got stuck. Thanks a lot! Everything works perfectly now!

Comment: cool, I was compelled to help once I saw you were playing rugby ;)

Comment: Haha, good to know it has it's perks besides more muscle strength ;)